# hiding the main object/class javascript

Tags: javascript

While doing javascript applications , I use the below convention to write my code.

I use a single javascript object to hold all my functions and runtime information.

This is a simple use case scenario for an example, Do not consider it as functional code.

```
    var main = {
        functOne: function(val){
               main.functTwo(parseInt(val));
        },
        functTwo: function(data){
               main.runtimeData = data;
        }
    }

Usage : <button onclick="main.functOne('123')">Click Me!</button>
```

This otherwise works ok but it is possible to view/change the properties and runtime information from the browser's console by accessing the object main.runtimeData .

So how can I restrict that kind of access without hindering the functionality?

Please add examples of some similar code if you can.

Comment: Attempts to control what the user does with code you send to their computer are doomed to failure.

Comment: @Quentin , I really could'nt understand what you meant.

Comment: It is impossible to effectively restrict access in the way you want.

Comment: It means that __you can't stop the user from tampering with your code__. If you need security then you should use server side scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is always "in the hands of the enemy". Having said that, a module pattern might help you hide away some functions. Edit: to reiterate, this is not secure or private, it's all in your user's hands.

```
var main = (function() {

    var x = {};

    // Private
    var private_var = "foo";

    // Public
    x.get_var = function() {

        return private_var;
    }

    return x;

}());
```

Very crude example, but it might help you. More info at [adequatelygood.com](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

Comment: Can you explain how this code works. Not all the bits and pieces ,only the structure related to my question. https://jquery-scrollview.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollview.js

Answer (score 2):

On a modern browser you could use [`freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to give some hindrance.

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. In essence the object is made effectively immutable. The method returns the object being frozen.

Comment: Can you explain how this code works. Not all the bits and pieces ,only the structure related to my question. https://jquery-scrollview.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollview.js

Comment: The MDN page that I linked to gives you a full description and examples, even an additional function called `deepFreeze`. What is it that you don't understand? [Here is a further link to the ECMA5 reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.9).